# How can I fix my heroku app and prevent it from crashing? at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: node.js, heroku

My app has always been working well, but suddenly it started crashing when I tried pushing to heroku.

Here are the logs:

```
2019-07-29T10:15:28.986142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2019-07-29T10:15:28.990123+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the jobdirecto@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-29T10:15:28.990128+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-29T10:15:29.002123+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-07-29T10:15:29.002127+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-29T10:15:29.002129+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-29T10_15_28_987Z-debug.log
2019-07-29T10:15:29.097390+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-29T10:15:29.077730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-29T14:10:35.913876+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-eyrie-16248.herokuapp.com request_id=8690ecb0-5c93-41f1-b861-1e2ecc194863 fwd="87.191.57.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-29T14:10:36.826030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-eyrie-16248.herokuapp.com request_id=df653f75-9e1f-46ab-a5ed-e867a8c95687 fwd="87.191.57.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is the node configuration:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV != "production") {
    app.use(
        "/bundle.js",
        require("http-proxy-middleware")({
            target: "http://localhost:8081/"
        })
    );
} else {
    app.use("/bundle.js", (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/bundle.js`));
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Please help me as I've been days trying to solve this and I still can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Those error messages aren't very helpful. There should be more detail above them in the logs that will give us more information. Please [edit] your question and include those lines. Note also that we're not going to go off-site to GitHub and dig through your code. You should include all relevant information _here_, directly in your question. We don't need your whole application, just a [mcve]. See [ask].

Comment: I update the info!

Comment: Thanks, but there's probably still more. Please include everything above that that starts with `npm ERR`.